# CSS - how to format content data-title text

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sLhmxtko/12/)  I would like to format text in my tooltip `data-title` so that I can add tags such as `<br>`.

For example:

```
    chart.renderer.html
('<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" data-title="<strong>Definisjon: (Innpendling/Sysselsatte) + (Utpendling/Lønnstakere og selvstendige etter bosted)</strong> 
    <br> 
    Forklaring: Arbeidsmarkedsintegrasjon er et mål for hvor godt arbeidsmarkedet i en kommune er integrert med arbeidsmarkedet utenfor. <br> 
    Høy verdi på denne indikatorer indikerer at kommunen/regionen er godt integrert med et arbeidsmarked utenfor kommunen."><i class="ion-help"></i></span>', 50, 22) 
.css({ color: 'black', fontSize: '20px' })
.add();
```

Comment: you can use tooltipster http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use html tags inside data-attr.

However, you can style the content with CSS using ::before and/or ::after pseudo elements.

```
    .has-tip::before {
        content: attr(data-title);
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .has-tip::after {
        content: attr(data-text);
    }
```